# AJAX not working in django production mode?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I've a django app deployed on heroku. In one of the section I asks for feedback and email of the person. If the email is valid email then I just reply Thank you. This is all being done using AJAX from getting values of form to returning thank you. It works fine in developement mode but not in prouction mode.

Here's my 'index.js'

```
function valid(email)
{
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test(email); 
}

$(document).on('submit','.Myform',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'',
        data:{
            message:$('#id_message').val(),
            email:$('#id_email').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function() {
            let validate = valid($('#id_email').val());
            if(validate){
                $('.Myform').fadeOut();
                $('.thank_you').fadeIn();
            }
            else{
                $('.Myform').show();
                alert('Please enter valid email address.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I've only one view in my app. So transferring data of AJAX to that view.

Here's my `views.py`

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = request.POST['message']
            email = request.POST['email']
            print(message)
            print(email)
            subject = "{} by {}".format(message,email)
            recipients = ['xyz@mail.com']
            sender = 'my@mail.com'
            send_mail(subject, message, sender ,recipients,fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponse('')
    else:
        form = ThoughtForm()

    return render(request,'my_webapp/index.html',{'form':form})
```

My `urls.py` file-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index')
]
```

In developement mode- It all works well.

**In production mode as soon as I hit submit button it shows me the loading gif but then it dissappears with no thank you message, no wrong email alert nothing happens and form vanishes**

The issue seems to be with the url. Can somebody help.

Here's the traceback error I'm getting in heroku logs-

```
Internal Server Error: /
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977239+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977241+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977243+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977246+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977248+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2019-10-07T18:30:33.97725+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977253+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977255+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/my_webapp/views.py", line 27, in index
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977257+00:00 app[web.1]: send_mail(subject, thoughts, sender ,recipients,fail_silently=False)
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977259+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977261+00:00 app[web.1]: return mail.send()
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977265+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977267+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977269+00:00 app[web.1]: new_conn_created = self.open()
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977271+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 70, in open
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977273+00:00 app[web.1]: self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977275+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977277+00:00 app[web.1]: raise last_exception
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977279+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977281+00:00 app[web.1]: initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977283+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977285+00:00 app[web.1]: raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
2019-10-07T18:30:33.977446+00:00 app[web.1]: smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q2sm7667020qkc.68 - gsmtp')
2019-10-07T18:30:33.978833+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.51.220.16 - - [07/Oct/2019:18:30:33 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 13750 "https://application.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0"
2019-10-07T18:30:33.980844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=application.herokuapp.com request_id=9bfdde45-dc5c-4fc6-bcee-4cdd3dd5aa72 fwd="103.212.146.48" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=191ms status=500 bytes=13976 protocol=https
```

Comment: And what do you see in your browser dev tools? Your ajax call doesn't have an `error` callback, but you should add that. If your server returns an error your ajax call just does what you describe: nothing. It might also be useful to look at the log files you produce on your production server (hopefully you setup logging so any error is logged to file or some other logging system)

Comment: When I went in Network section of chrome and upon hitting the submit button on feedback from I'm getting Status-code:500, Internal server error.

Comment: Then you need to look at your django logs for the full error trace

Comment: Unable to understand logs error it is showing-
`
Internal Server Error: /
2019-10-07T18:22:12.174292+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-07T18:22:12.174295+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
2019-10-07T18:22:12.174297+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
`
Don't know why its working fine in development but not in production.

Comment: There should be more than that. Paste the entire trace in your question.

Comment: I did. Please check.

Comment: Your Google mail credentials are not accepted

Comment: What to do then? You have any solution. I'm unable to find something on the internet.

Comment: Have you enabled 2FA? In that case username/password doesn’t work. Read the documentation in the link the error gives you.

Comment: did you solve this problem. I am facing the same problem.